# ASP.NET Core External Identity Provider Login problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I've tried to implement Google Login in my API, but the table "AspNetUserLogins" in SQL won't get populated.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string? returnUrl = null) 
{

    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); 

    if (info == null) { 
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login)); 
    }

    var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    if (signInResult.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ForgotPassword));
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        ViewData["Provider"] = info.LoginProvider;
        var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginModel { Email = email });
    }
}
```

On the "var signInResult", I get "failed" and I can't access the If statement. Can you please help me?

I've tried many different solutions, but none of them worked.

Comment: Does the answer below useful to you ? If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I found that Google and other three-party logins cannot be used like Asp.Net Core Identity, and can be used directly after modification.

**When using Google provide.**

1. we need add below code in controller

   ```
    [HttpPost("google-login")]
    public IActionResult GoogleLogin()
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/api/authentication/google-login-callback" };
        return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [HttpGet("google-login-callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleLoginCallback()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest("Failed to authenticate with Google.");
        }

        var user = new
        {
            Id = result.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value,
            Email = result.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value,
            Name = result.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value
        };

        // TODO: Create or update user account in your database.

        return Ok(new { User = user });
    }
   ```

**2. And I replace the form tag in Login.cshtml like below.**

[image]

**3. Test Result**

[image]

---

In Asp.Net Core Identity, we can change the code to api endpoint directly like below.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginApi(string? returnUrl, InputModel? Input)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Ok("Invalid login attempt.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Ok("Invalid model.");
    }
```